# Building an external static library in CMake, and including the result

Tags: c++, linux, makefile, build, cmake

My C++ project has a dependency to a library, that I have the source for in a subdirectory. This external library has an option 'build_static_lib' for building it as a static library in its CMakeLists.txt file.

In my top directory CMakeLists.txt, my understanding is that this **should** be simple:

```
add_executable(myproject ${SOURCES})

set(build_static_lib ON)
add_subdirectory(${CMAKE_SOURCE_DIR}/subdirectory/external_project)
unset(build_static_lib)

....

target_link_libraries(myproject PRIVATE externalproject another_library)
```

When I run this, my sources are built, then during the `make`, I am given an error that it cannot find `-lexternalproject`.

The strange thing is, when I change CMakeLists.txt (or delete the CMakeCache), and run it again, suddenly it successfully builds the `libexternalproject` and links it correctly.

Am I missing something? My journey with CMake has been unbelievably painful and any suggestions would be appreciated. It seems like every online resource has a very different strategy, and none of them quite achieve this presumably simple case. Thanks!

EDIT:

The content of the external project's CMakeLists.txt is https://github.com/muflihun/easyloggingpp/blob/master/CMakeLists.txt:

```
if (build_static_lib)
    if (lib_utc_datetime)
            add_definitions(-DELPP_UTC_DATETIME)
    endif()

    require_cpp11()
    add_library(easyloggingpp STATIC src/easylogging++.cc)

    install(TARGETS
        easyloggingpp
        ARCHIVE DESTINATION lib)
endif()
```

Comment: What content of `CMakeLists.txt` under `${CMAKE_SOURCE_DIR}/subdirectory/external_project` is? Does it call `ExternalProject_Add` for build the external project?

Comment: Hi Tsyvarev, I've added the full `CMakeLists.txt` to the question.

Comment: @ricky116 Can you run `VERBOSE=1 make` to have more detailed output of the compilation process, and provide the command that fails?